# How to get the value of a property of an object in an array in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to get the value of a property of an object in an array.
I am sending the following items to Google Tag Manager.

```
items: [{id: 'exampleX', price: '9999'},{id: 'exampleY', price: '9999'},{id: 'exampleZ', price: '9999'}]
```

Is there any other way to get the price of exampleX but with custom JavaScript?
Or is there a simpler way to get it?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
const items = [{id: 'exampleX', price: '9999'},{id: 'exampleY', price: '9999'},{id: 'exampleZ', price: '9999'}]

const price = items.filter(e => e.id === "exampleX").pop()?.price;
console.log(price)
```

- `items.filter(e => e.id === "exampleX")` matches every element where `id==="exampleX"`
- `.pop()` to get the first element from array (might be null if no element is found)
- `?.price` safe unwrap to get property price (undefined if no element was found)

---

Update:

```js
const items = [{id: 'exampleX', price: '9999'},{id: 'exampleY', price: '9999'},{id: 'exampleZ', price: '9999'}]

const price = items[0].price; // first element = index 0
console.log(price)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
I want to get the price of the first id.  
In some cases, the first id is exampleA, exampleB, etc.  
How can I specify that it is the first id without specifying exampleX?
Best Regards,

Comment: Thank you! It did exactly what I wanted it to do.